# Domain of solution of separable equation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose we have a separable equation $(t-a)x' = x$, where $x=x(t)$ and $a\in\mathbb R$ is fixed.

Per [this discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1443941/solving-the-differential-equation-y-2xy-y0-2) the equation has constant solutions or solutions we find via separating. Clearly, $x(t)=0, t\in D$ (more on that in a minute) is a solution. After separating we get
$$\frac{1}{x}dx = \frac{1}{t-a}dt \implies x = C(t-a),\quad C\neq 0 $$ 
My question is about the domain of the function $x$. A solution found by separating doesn't show any problem with $t=a$, but when we separated the variables, we clearly had to assume $t\neq a$, otherwise the operation would have been illegitimate.

We have a family of straight lines as solutions. <s>Do they now have removable discontinuities at $t=a$?</s>. What's the story with $t=a$ or is it relevant? Can we ignore the free variable when separating?

---

Ok, maybe this was a lucky shot. Consider, instead $2xx'\sin t = 1$. Constant solutions are impossible and we also must have $\sin t\neq 0$. After separating we have
$$2xdx = \frac{1}{\sin t}dt \implies x^2 = \ln \left\lvert \tan\frac{t}{2} \right\rvert  +C$$
If we consider the first equation as 
$$ \frac{t-a}{x}x' = 1 $$
then comparing the two equations, in one case $t=a$ is irrelevant although initially it must be that $t\neq a$, otherwise the identity doesn't hold. In the other case $t=k\pi$ cannot hold from the get go and is a calamity for a solution.

---

Is it then safe to say we may ignore the free variable when separating? Is the domain of solution to be decided individually? Perhaps, there is a theorem that describes solutions to a specific equation $f(x,t,x') = c$ and there's also something assumed about the domain of $f$. I don't know what I'm looking for, though.

Comment: Usually if the coefficient of the highest-order derivative is zero, we call that a singularity. That's why it shows up in your solution as a problem. There are various existence and uniqueness theorems that take singularities into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not have to remove discontinuities at t=a. The family of curves $$ x=C(t-a)$$ satisfies you equation $$ (t-a)x'=x$$ for every $C$ at every $t$ and that is what you are looking for.

Note that the family   $$ x=C(t-a)$$  covers all the cases including the constant solution $x=0$.
What I am trying to say is that once you have a solution, which satisfies your equation, you do not worry about the method which was used to get that solution.

Comment: Well, we certainly don't worry after finding and checking, but what's to say we never have to worry? Perhaps, this was a lucky shot with the choice of equation.